# Missing labels on Feynman Graph using feynmf

Tags: feynmf, metafont

I'm trying to create a Feynman graph using the feynmf package. My minimal example is

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmf}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{diagram}

  \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmfbottom{b}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,b}
    \fmflabel{i1}{i1}
    \fmflabel{i2}{i2}
    \fmflabel{o1}{o1}
    \fmflabel{o2}{o2}
    \fmflabel{b}{b}
  \end{fmfgraph*}

\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

After compiling once, I have the graph but not the labels (as expected, I guess...). I get the error

```
pdflatex> feynmf: Label file diagram.t1 not found:

pdflatex> feynmf: Process diagram.mf with METAFONT and then reprocess this file.
```

OK, so I do as told and try to process the .mf file with Metafont in my terminal (using Xubuntu) with

```
mpost diagram.mf
```

And then I get stuck. It starts then stops with a question mark, and I don't know how to proceed or what Metapost is trying to tell me:

```
This is MetaPost, version 1.803 (kpathsea version 6.1.1)
(mpost.mp (/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/metapost/base/plain.mp
Preloading the plain mem file, version 1.004) ) (./diagram.mf
(/usr/share/texmf/metafont/feynmf/feynmf.mf
>> mode_setup
! Isolated expression.
<to be read again> 
                   ;
l.117 mode_setup;

?
```

Can anyone help? How can I get my labels?
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3):

The program to call is not Metapost, but Metafont:

```
mf diagram.mf
```

However, it's better to use `feynmp` that has the same syntax and produces Metapost files: you'll get `diagram.mp` and running `mpost diagram.mp` will do.

There's another possibility:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{feynmp-auto} % or \usepackage{feynmp}

\begin{document}

\begin{fmffile}{diagram}

  \begin{fmfgraph*}(40,25)
    \fmfleft{i1,i2}
    \fmfright{o1,o2}
    \fmfbottom{b}
    \fmf{fermion}{i2,v1,o2}
    \fmf{photon}{v1,b}
    \fmflabel{i1}{i1}
    \fmflabel{i2}{i2}
    \fmflabel{o1}{o1}
    \fmflabel{o2}{o2}
    \fmflabel{b}{b}
  \end{fmfgraph*}

\end{fmffile}

\end{document}
```

The package `feynmp-auto` (which I'm the author of) even avoids the need of running manually `mpost`: the diagram is compiled at the end of a run (with `pdflatex` only if the source has been modified in the current LaTeX run) and will correctly place it at the next LaTeX run.

[image]